# Trouble Updating WSL Ubuntu: 404 Not Found Error and Repository Issue

Tags: package-management, updates, ppa, repository

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to update my WSL Ubuntu system using the command `sudo apt update`. Here are the details of the problem:

**Distributor ID:** Ubuntu
**Description:** Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
**Release:** 22.04
**Codename:** jammy
Upon running the update, I encounter the following error related to a repository:

```
Ign:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.80 443]
```

This issue is preventing me from updating the system securely, and I receive additional warnings related to repository configuration.

Any insights into resolving this 404 Not Found error and addressing the repository issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The repository doesn't contain any packages for Ubuntu 22.04 (`jammy`). It contains packages only for Ubuntu 14.04 (`trusty`).

Disable the repository:

```
sudo sed -e '/mc3man/s/^/#/' -i /etc/apt/sources.list{.d/*,}
```

Then:

```
sudo apt update
```

[mc3man on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/%7Emc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media)